# Search both elements of a pair and replace either element

Tags: c++, replace, std-pair

Given a pair of ints `p`, I want to be able to replace any `2` in it with a `3` and vice versa, so I did something like this:

```cpp
pair<int,int> f(pair<int, int> p) {

    if (p.first == 2)
        p.first = 3;
    else if (p.first == 3)
        p.first = 2;

    if (p.second == 2)
        p.second = 3;
    else if (p.second == 3)
        p.second = 2;

    return p;
}
```

But, if there were more than just these two numbers that I wanted to replace, each to the other, the function would be irritating to write. How can I do this, for just this example, without needing to write four if statements, or with less code so that it could be extended to more numbers which may need to be replaced?

Comment: _But, if there were more than just these two numbers that I wanted to replace_ you mean passing tuple to the `f`?

Comment: No, I meant that I might like to replace all the 5s with 7s and all the 8s with 12s, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `std::map` to store what to replace as a key and replacement as a value:

```cpp
std::pair<int, int> f(std::pair<int, int> p) {
    static const std::map<int, int> replacements = {
        { 2, 3 },  // 2 -> 3
        { 5, 7 }   // 5 -> 7
        // Add more replacements
    };

    auto it = replacements.find(p.first);
    if (it != replacements.end()) {
        p.first = it->second;
    }

    // Same with p.second

    return p;
}
```

Also you can pass by reference to get rid of unnecessary copy:

```cpp
void f(std::pair<int, int>& p) {
    // Same as above, but no return 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, I'd factor out the duplication between `p.first` and `p.second`.

```cpp
void maybe_replace_element(int& element)
{
    if (element == 2)
        element = 3
    else if (element == 3)
        element = 2
}

pair<int,int> f(pair<int, int> p) {
    maybe_replace_element(p.first);
    maybe_replace_element(p.second);
    return p;
}
```

This halves the number of if-statements.

Then, if you had more numbers to add, I think it would be reasonable to continue the `else if` pattern:

```cpp
void maybe_replace_element(int& element)
{
    if (element == 2)
        element = 3
    else if (element == 3)
        element = 2
    else if (element == 5)
        element = 7
    else if (element == 8)
        element = 12
}
```

But you could also use something like a [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map):

```
const std::unordered_map<int, int> REPLACEMENTS = {
    {2, 3}, // Replace 2 with 3.
    {3, 2}, // Replace 3 with 2.
    {5, 7}, // etc.
    {8, 12}
};

void maybe_replace_element(int& element)
{
    auto replacement = REPLACEMENTS.find(element);
    if (replacement != REPLACEMENTS.end())
        element = replacement->second;
}
```

Comment: Or even a `switch`/`case`. The code gen for `switch`/`if` is very good (small and fast) compared to `std::map`, so that should be preferable.